# HashMap pair.getValue returning ArrayList when it should return Array, Java

Tags: arrays, arraylist, groovy, hashmap

I have the following HashMap:

`Map<String, String[]> aMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>()`

and a method with the following signature:

`private boolean verifyFileName(String fileName, String[] allowableValues)`

I invoke the method like this:

`Map.Entry<String, String[]> pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();`

`...`

`verifyFileName(file.getName(), pair.getValue())`

The problem is that `verifyFileName` throws an error saying that its second argument is an `ArrayList`. When I change the signature of `verifyFileName` to `(String fileName, ArrayList<String> allowableValues)` the error disappears.

What's going on here?

EDIT: Here's the JUnit test I use the HashMap in (written in Groovy):

```
   @Test
    public void verifyGeneratedAndCompiledFiles() { 
        Iterator it = DIRECTORIES_TO_CHECK.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String[]> pair = it.next();
            int count = 0
            File createdFolder = new File(pair.getKey())
            for (File file: createdFolder.listFiles()) {
               println('checking for ' + file.getName())               
                if (file.length() == 0) {
                    fail(createdFolder.getPath() + ' folder contains an empty file')
                }

                if (!verifyFileName(file.getName(), pair.getValue())) {
                    fail(createdFolder.getPath() + ' folder is missing ' + file.getName())
                }
                count++
            }

            if (count != 2) {
                fail(createdFolder.getName() + " folder contains an incorrect number of files")
            }

            count = 0
        }       
    }
```

and here's where I declare and initialize `DIRECTORIES_TO_CHECK`:

```
  private static final Map<String, String[]> DIRECTORIES_TO_CHECK
    static {
        Map<String, String[]> aMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>()
        aMap.put(DIRECTORIES_ROOT + "subproj/build/classes/generatedSource", ["Subproj.class", "Subproj2.class"])
        aMap.put(DIRECTORIES_ROOT + "sub2/build/classes/generatedSource", ["Sub2.class", "Sub22.class"])
        aMap.put(DIRECTORIES_ROOT + "subproj/generated/java", ["Subproj.java, Subproj2.java"])
        aMap.put(DIRECTORIES_ROOT + "sub2/generated/java", ["Sub2.java", "Sub22.java"])
        DIRECTORIES_TO_CHECK = Collections.unmodifiableMap(aMap)
    }
```

Comment: What's `pair.getValue()`?

Comment: Why do you have a cast at `(Map.Entry)it.next();`? Trouble keeping your generic parameters in condition? Using raw types will certainly make it easier to have class cast exceptions during runtime.

Comment: @Kayaman I copied an "iterate over a hashmap" snippet from another question. It's left over from that. Could it be causing problems?

Comment: Yes. You're casting to (or just using) a raw type and losing the compile time type checking. Most likely the reason is that you've been copying code randomly without understanding what it does. Now you have a piece of garbage that doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a poluted heap. How did you get the HashMap? Somewhere you used an unsafe case and filled ArrayList<String> into the Map.

Comment: Are you creating the HashMap with groovy? that fragment is not valid java.

Comment: @k5_ Yes. I'll edit the question

Comment: ["Sub2.java", "Sub22.java"] is an `ArrayList<String>` in groovy

Comment: @k5_ Thanks a lot. I know this question has some issues, thanks for assisting anyway. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @Kayaman Could you make your criticism more constructive? Do you have any good references you could suggest?

Comment: It's really hard to provide constructive commentary from the given material. Read the tutorials, learn the language, don't copy/paste code that you don't understand...

Comment: Based on this tutorial: http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/ It seems like my mistake was using generics *and* casting. I should pick one or the other, or better yet use a for each loop.